# Export specific multiband image of Sentinel-2 in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am interested in removing cloud in https://code.earthengine.google.com/d9aaa276f0fa1ab33e78230e8f348c6f.
I try to export specific multiband to GDrive in GEE. I try to write the sintax :

```
Export.image.toDrive({
   image: s2_sr_median,
   description: 'image_export',
   folder: 'ee_demos',
   region: region,
   scale: 10,
   crs: 'EPSG:4326'
   });
```

But, the result all band will be exported. So, how to export specific multiband, for example band 2,3,4, and band 8. I have try this sintax, but not successfull. There is a message : Line 123: Unexpected arguments to function toDrive(): band.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
   image: s2_sr_median,
   description: 'image_export',
   folder: 'ee_demos',
   band: ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'],
   region: region,
   scale: 10,
   crs: 'EPSG:4326'
   });
```

So, how is the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `select()` the bands after doing the `median()`. You can do it in two ways. Either you can use the index of the bands starting from 0.

```
var s2_sr_median = (s2_sr_cld_col.map(add_cld_shdw_mask)
                             .map(apply_cld_shdw_mask)
                             .median()).select([1,2,3,7])
```

Or, if you do not want to go with the index, you can use the expression with band names. When the sequence breaks, put `|` between the band names.

```
var s2_sr_median = (s2_sr_cld_col.map(add_cld_shdw_mask)
                             .map(apply_cld_shdw_mask)
                             .median()).select('B[2-4]|B8')
```

Comment: thank you. it is work